# Image Stabilization Issue in LGV30

Tags: android, video, android-camera2

Video suddenly zooming into the frame when recording starts in preview mode is known behavior, but the issue I am facing currently is the extreme jump in preview when using LGV30.

1. In pixel 1 XL and pixel 2 XL the jump is negligible
2. In Samsung S8+ the jump is visible but can be considered for the final smoother videos
3. But in LGV30 the jump is terrible, the video moves to the extreme top right corner of the preview and the final output quality of the video is worse than VGA.

I know that Image Stabilization is dependent on the combination of Sensor Orientation, Gyroscope and Accelerometer and the jump in video is decided by the quality of these sensors, but is there any way I can control the Jump in LGV30 or is it the hardware that has flaw.

I am writing down my configuration code for reference

```
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE_FAST);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT_VIDEO_RECORD);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.HOT_PIXEL_MODE, CaptureRequest.HOT_PIXEL_MODE_FAST);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_FAST);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_FAST);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE, CaptureRequest.TONEMAP_MODE_FAST);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SHADING_MODE, CaptureRequest.SHADING_MODE_FAST);
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON);
```

I assume that this jump can not be controlled, but is there any way to reduce the jump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be the wrong camera.

Sounds trivial but in this code

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
manager.getCameraIdList()
```

The manager returns all the accessible camera for a given device.
In LGV30 since there are 2 rear cameras, one regular and another wide angle, I was accessing the wide angle camera.

Wide angle camera was not able to handle the Image Stabilization and was causing this issue. So the solution was to pick the first camera from the list for given camera facing. This is still a workaround because I couldn't figure out the API to check whether given camera is regular or workaround.

Details for above question is in [How to check whether given Camera is regular camera or wide angle camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929422/how-to-check-whether-given-camera-is-regular-camera-or-wide-angle-camera)